# Why the play stop pause buttons and progressBar are not displaying at all?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is the jsfiddler for it the issue is with the big images i wanted to add the buttons play stop pause and the progressbar on the big images: [JSFiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/6rqryo6s/)

When i'm doing inspect element i don't see any errors in red.
I took the code of this jquery: [Automatic slideshow with a timer, play-, pause-, previous- and next-](http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/21/)

And before it i used the coolcarousels this jquery: Cool responsive image slider with thumbnail carousel

[Cool responsive image slider](http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/28/)

And this is the code i have now:

In the html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="carousel.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="glow-effect.css">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.caroufredsel/6.1.0/jquery.carouFredSel.packed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://malsup.github.io/jquery.cycle2.js"></script>
        <script src="http://malsup.github.io/jquery.cycle2.carousel.js"></script>
        <script src="java_script.js"></script>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <style>.container {
    background: rgb(170, 187, 97); /* Fallback */
    background: rgba(170, 187, 97, 0.5);
}</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>TODO write content</div>

        <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="carousel-wrapper">
        <img id="shadow" src="img/gui/carousel_shadow.png" />
                <div id="inner">
        <div id="carousel">
            <span id="pixar"><img src="http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/radar-simulation-files/radar007339.Gif" /></span>
            <span id="bugs"><img src="http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/radar-simulation-files/radar005712.Gif" /></span>
            <span id="cars"><img src="http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/radar-simulation-files/radar007337.Gif" /></span>
            <span id="incred"><img src="http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/radar-simulation-files/radar000009.Gif" /></span>
            <span id="monsters"><img src="http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/radar-simulation-files/radar000007.Gif" /></span>
            <span id="nemo"><img src="http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/radar-simulation-files/radar005720.Gif" /></span>
                        <span id="radar"><img src="http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/radar-simulation-files/radar007338.Gif" /></span>
            <span id="rat"><img src="http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/radar-simulation-files/radar003137.Gif" /></span>
            <span id="toystory"><img src="http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/radar-simulation-files/radar000005.Gif" /></span>
            <span id="up"><img src="http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/radar-simulation-files/radar003138.Gif" /></span>
            <span id="walle"><img src="http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/radar-simulation-files/radar000006.Gif" /></span>
                        <div id="navi">
            <div id="timer"></div>
            <a id="prev" href="#"></a>
            <a id="play" href="#"></a>
            <a id="next" href="#"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="thumbs-wrapper">
        <div id="thumbs">
            <a href="#pixar" class="selected"><img src="img/small/pixar.jpg" /></a>
            <a href="#bugs"><img src="img/small/bugs.jpg" /></a>
            <a href="#cars"><img src="img/small/cars.jpg" /></a>
            <a href="#incred"><img src="img/small/incred.jpg" /></a>
            <a href="#monsters"><img src="img/small/monsters.jpg" /></a>
            <a href="#nemo"><img src="img/small/nemo.jpg" /></a>
                        <a href="#radar"><img src="img/small/radar002665resized.jpg" /></a>
            <a href="#rat"><img src="img/small/rat.jpg" /></a>
            <a href="#toystory"><img src="img/small/toystory.jpg"  /></a>
            <a href="#up"><img src="img/small/up.jpg" /></a>
            <a href="#walle"><img src="img/small/walle.jpg" /></a>
        </div>
        <a id="prev" href="#"></a>
        <a id="next" href="#"></a>
    </div>
</div>
        <div class="carousel">
        <div class="container">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
        <div class="container">Lorem ipsum_for_testing dolor</div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

I added to the html file this part:

```
<div id="inner">
```

And

```
<div id="timer"></div>
<a id="prev" href="#"></a>
<a id="play" href="#"></a>
<a id="next" href="#"></a>
```

Then the javascript file:

```
$(function() {

    $('#carousel span').append('<img src="img/gui/carousel_glare.png" class="glare" />');
    $('#thumbs a').append('<img src="img/gui/carousel_glare_small.png" class="glare" />');
    $('#carousel').carouFredSel({
                prev: '#prev',
        next: '#next',
        auto: {
            button: '#play',
            progress: '#timer',
            pauseOnEvent: 'resume'
        },
        responsive: true,
        circular: false,
        auto: true,
                infinite: true,
        items: {
            visible: 1,
            width: 200,
            height: '56%'
        },
        scroll: {
            fx: 'directscroll',
                        pauseOnHover: true,
                        duration: 500
        }
    });

    $('#thumbs').carouFredSel({
        responsive: true,
        circular: false,
        infinite: false,
        auto: false,
        prev: '#prev',
        next: '#next',
        items: {
            visible: {
                min: 2,
                max: 6
            },
            width: 150,
            height: '66%'
        }
    });

    $('#thumbs a').click(function() {
        $('#carousel').trigger('slideTo', '#' + this.href.split('#').pop() );
        $('#thumbs a').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        return false;
    });
        $('#wrapper').hover(function() {
        $('#navi').stop().animate({
            bottom: 0
        });
    }, function() {
        $('#navi').stop().animate({
            bottom: -60
        });
    });

});
```

And the css file:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
body {
    background: url(img/gui/bg_glare.png) top center no-repeat #bcc;
}
html > body {
    min-height: 600px;
}
body * {
    font-family: Arial, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #333;
    line-height: 22px;
}

#wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    left: 25%;
    top: 50px;
}
#carousel-wrapper {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
#carousel, #thumbs {
    overflow: hidden;
}
#carousel-wrapper .caroufredsel_wrapper {
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #899;
}

#carousel span, #carousel img,
#thumbs a, #thumbs img  {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
#carousel span, #carousel a,
#thumbs span, #thumbs a {
    position: relative;
}
#carousel img,
#thumbs img {
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
#carousel img.glare,
#thumbs img.glare {
    width: 102%;
    height: auto;
}

#carousel span {
    width: 554px;
    height: 313px;
}

#thumbs-wrapper {
    padding: 20px 40px;
    position: relative;
}
#thumbs a {
    border: 2px solid #899;
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 10px;

    -webkit-transition: border-color .5s;
    -moz-transition: border-color .5s;
    -ms-transition: border-color .5s;
    transition: border-color .5s;
}
#thumbs a:hover, #thumbs a.selected {
    border-color: #566;
}

#wrapper img#shadow {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}

#prev, #next {
    background: transparent url('img/gui/carousel_nav.png') no-repeat 0 0;
    display: block;
    width: 19px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
}
#prev {
    background-position: 0 0;
    left: 10px;
}
#next {
    background-position: -19px 0;
    right: 10px;
}           
#prev:hover { 
    background-position: 0 -20px;               
}
#next:hover {
    background-position: -19px -20px;               
}
#prev.disabled, #next.disabled {
    display: none !important;
}
```

In the css file i didn't change the code in the javascript file i added:

```
prev: '#prev',
        next: '#next',
        auto: {
            button: '#play',
            progress: '#timer',
            pauseOnEvent: 'resume'
        },
```

And

```
$('#wrapper').hover(function() {
        $('#navi').stop().animate({
            bottom: 0
        });
    }, function() {
        $('#navi').stop().animate({
            bottom: -60
        });
    });
```

The first jquery of the carousel is still working fine the second link.
But the new one with the play stop pause buttons i don't see them at all.

What i mean is something like this and somehow also to change the colors of the buttons play stop pause to fit the color of the big images maybe something more light or transparent color.

[image: Screenshot]

And the pause stop play should handle the big images not the small ones.

Comment: I added it to jsfiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/6rqryo6s/ the big images that move from right to left on those i wanted to add the play stop button with the progress.

Comment: What i wanted to do is compbination of this jquery: http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/28/ i mean to keep the small images and add to this big images the play pause stop buttons and progressbar from http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/21/ but only the part of the buttons and progressbar and put them on the first one big images.